# Prove Newtons method converges quadratically

Tags: convergence-divergence, quadratics, newton-raphson

f(x)= cosh(x) +cos(x) -3

Let x* be the none negative root of f. Prove that Newton's Method applied to f converges quadratically to x*.

Really confused where to start for a proof. I understand that if the second derivative of f(x*) doesn't equal 0 it converges precisely quadratic.

But don't no how to start or what to include. Looked through a few books and it gets very confusing!

Comment: Take the second derivative of $f$, see where it is nonzero...

Comment: ok o the 2nd derivative is cosh(x)-cos(x) which is non zero everywhere apart from the origin?

Comment: And is the origin a possible value for $x^*$? If it is then you do not know that it converges quadratically. It it is not, then all the possible values of $x^*$ are values which f has nonzero second derivative so it converges quadratically.

Comment: no its not a possible value of x* but why does possible all values of x* being values which f has a nonzero second derivative make it quadratic convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain. Take as true the following statement:

If the second derivative of $f(x^*)$ is nonzero, then newton's theorem converges quadratically to $x^*$.

Now, to show that newton's method converges quadratically we only have to show that $f''(x^*)\neq 0$. The problem is we don't know what $x^*$ is so we have to consider all the possible values it could take on. The good news is that $f''(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\neq 0$. Thus, as long as $x^*\neq 0$, $f''(x^*) \neq 0$. How can we conclude $x^*\neq 0$? We can substitute 0 into the function and see it is not 0, $f(0)=1+1-3=-1\neq 0$. Thus, whatever $x^*$ is, it is nonzero, and thus we can conclude that $f''(x^*)\neq 0$ and thus newton's method converges quadratically to $x^*$.

Comment: great answer thanks for explaining it to me

Answer (score 0):

And,
of course,
the reason for the
quadratic convergence
is that
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+O(h^2)
$
so,
if
$h = -f(x)/f'(x)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x-f(x)/f'(x))
&=f(x)+f'(x)(-f(x)/f'(x))+O((f(x)/f'(x))^2)\\
&=O((f(x)/f'(x))^2)\\
&=O((f(x))^2)\\
\end{array}
$

if $f'(x)$
is bounded away from zero.